# How to query mongodb with laravel to get records which match to first found record and to the Nth number

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent, mongodb-query

I am looking for Laravel + Mongodb query to find substitute list of Product.
For example, basically query for abc(product-new) then it find document and again search for xyz(product-old) and it would be until the last matching document. According to below collection the result would be xyz, pqr, opq.

Product collection structure:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| product-new | product-old |
+-------------+-------------+
| abc         | xyz         |
| xyz         | pqr         |
| pqr         | opq         |
| dys         | mnp         |
| mnp         | rst         |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I have integrated below code but I am sure it's not proper way,

```
$productid = 'abc'; //sample product id
for($i = 0; $i < $perPage; $i++){
  $product = Product::where("product-new", $productid)->get()->toArray();
  if($product){
     $result[] = $product[0];
     $productid = $product[0]['product-old']; //xyz
  }
```

But want to do it through single query.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine as it is. The only issues are

(1) That it will return, at most, `$perPage` items. But I suspect that is what you want.

(2) There is no code to break out of the loop if `$product` is false. E.g. you could have:

```
 if ($product){
     $result[] = $product[0];
     $productid = $product[0]['product-old']; //xyz
 } else {
     break;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @PhilHunt, but I need a query to get the records instead of looping.

Comment: I don't think a MongoDB query can do what you want, not all in one query. Not unless you read the whole collection in and then go through it in your PHP code.